# iphone: unable to deploy app on iphone

Tags: iphone, ios-provisioning

I have downloaded the certificate from developer portal, downloaded provisioning profile organizer is showing provisioning profiles I have provisioning profile installed on my device as well

but when I am trying to change change the developer profile 
then getting this error

"The name (“common name”) of a valid code-signing certificate in a keychain within your keychain path.   A missing or invalid certificate will cause a build error.  [CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY]"

Comment: This error not effect anything. you can make ur ipa and install on device and it will work. or upload on iTunes and that will submitted successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem has been fixed by changing the Application's Identifier from '59R497CZ5Y.com.markmckie.ccna' to 'com.markmckie.ccna'

Resource: [Error Whilst Compiling App](https://discussions.apple.com/message/10510276?messageID=10510276)